# How to set image with text having below it in gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout

I try in following way but I am getting Null Pointer Exception at  iv.setImageBitmap(bm). 
I try to set images with text using grid view and Layout Inflater.I also did debuging process but still I am not able to get solution.Please check the following code.

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
public static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 10;
int id=-1;
public CategoryAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
 }
public int getCount() {
    return CategorylogoActivity.logoarray.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Bitmap bm=null;
       ImageView iv = null ;
       TextView tv=null;
       View v;
                    if(convertView==null){

                        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

                        v = li.inflate(R.layout.category_icon, null);
                        tv= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);

                        iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        v = convertView;
                    }
                        try {
                            URL aURL = new URL(CategorylogoActivity.logoarray[position]);
                            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                            conn.connect();
                            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                            // Buffered is always good for a performance plus. 
                            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                            // Decode url-data to a bitmap. 
                            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

                            bis.close();
                            is.close();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    tv.setText(CategorylogoActivity.namearray[0]);

                    return v;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static class viewHolder {
       ImageView iv = null ;
       TextView tv=null;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Bitmap bm=null;
       viewHolder vh;
       View v;
                    if(convertView==null){
                        vh = new viewHolder();
                        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
                        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  


                        v = li.inflate(R.layout.category_icon, null);
                        vh.tv= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);

                        vh.iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);

                        v.setTag(vh);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vh = (viewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                        v = convertView;
                    }
                        try {
                            URL aURL = new URL(CategorylogoActivity.logoarray[position]);
                            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                            conn.connect();
                            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                            // Buffered is always good for a performance plus. 
                            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                            // Decode url-data to a bitmap. 
                            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

                            bis.close();
                            is.close();
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     vh.iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    vh.tv.setText(CategorylogoActivity.namearray[0]);

                    return v;
```

you have to use viewHolder kind of object, when the convertView is not null, your iv imageView is null . so you are using setImageBitmap() on null object. try my code.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for quick and very accurate answer to my query.Thanks allot.I ts working properly with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do URLConnection in your adapter, this will try to do multiples connection, cause getView() will be called each time you display that view in your adapter. Handle instead the connection in a separate class.